# Preventing Access from asking to Save the form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a navigation form with a research area and a thumbnail area showing differents details according to the criteria taped.

For instance, the user taps the name of a company (let's say "Abidas") and press *search*, that creates a SQL query affected to a String. This SQL "query" is then assigned and adapted to the *RecordSource* variable of each thumbnail (one thumbnail for the contacts at "Abidas", another one with the finances of "Abidas"...).

The SQL query works fine but each time the users moves from one thumbnail to another. For instance, if you are on the *"contact"* thumbnail and you go to the *"Finances"* thumbnail Access would ask *"Would you want to save the Form "contacts"?"* (translated from French UI).

Does anyone knows a way to stop this message from appearing? Maybe there is an easier way to show the results of the search

Thanks!

Comment: This is a concern. No where should users ever affect the design of any application object including forms, queries, reports, macros, modules during the runtime of application. So such a message should not appear in a well-designed app. Can you screenshot your form? I don't know what you mean by thumbnail.Are they simply buttons with labels?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Docmd.Close to close the form when you switch, you can choose not to save:

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo
```

The values are `acSaveNo`, `acSaveYes`, `acSavePrompt` with Prompt being the default